# Why assemblyBinding is ignored?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, web-config, iis-7.5

I have an IIS Application defined under the "Default Web Site" for which I would like to use a common assembly defined in another directory than /bin. I added a  section to the web.config of the IIS Application with the location of the common assembly. However, it appears that that the assemblyBinding is ignored. Why is it ignored?

```
<runtime>
    <probing privatePath="C:\Program Files\MyProduct\Bin\" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MyProduct.Security" publicKeyToken="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" culture="neutral" />
            <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="file:///c:\program files\myproduct\bin\MyProduct.Security.dll" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> If the assembly has a strong name, the codebase setting can be
>   anywhere on the local intranet or the Internet. If the assembly is a
>   private assembly, the codebase setting must be a path relative to the
>   application's directory.

Comment: The assembly has a strong name.

Comment: After you set the registry keys a reboot is required